# Add custom matchers to Playwright with Typescript support

Tags: typescript, playwright

There is a page [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend) to write a custom matcher to the Playwright.

```js
// playwright.config.ts
import { expect, PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

expect.extend({
  toBeWithinRange(received: number, floor: number, ceiling: number) {
    const pass = received >= floor && received <= ceiling;
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () => 'passed',
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => 'failed',
        pass: false,
      };
    }
  },
});

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {};
export default config;
```

but in the last line, they have mentioned:

> For TypeScript, also add the following to `global.d.ts`. You don't need it for JavaScript.

There is no following code!

Could you please help me to find out how to write a Typescript compatible code in `global.d.ts`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// global.d.ts
declare global {
 namespace PlaywrightTest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toBeWithinRange(a: number, b: number): R;
    }
  }
}
```

Something like that will work with Playwright Test Expect.

Comment: Refer to the documentation for the correct declaration of global.d.ts https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You can't extend `expect` because of the type declarations they use.

You should open an issue for that documentation.

Looking at the type declarations, we see that `Expect` is a type alias and not an interface...

Which means we can't augment this type...

If they changed it to an interface then we could augment the module and add our extensions.

So for that, you also might want to open an issue or a pull request to fix it (fixing it is literally changing one line or two).